# React bind function to call child function?

Tags: reactjs, bind, toast

I am trying to understand this code

```
    ReactDOM.render(<ToastManager notify={this.bindNotify} />, portalElement);
  }

  bindNotify = (fn: Function) => {
    this.createNotification = fn;
  };

  notify = (message: MessageProp, options: MessageOptionalOptions = {}) => {
    if (this.createNotification) {
      this.createNotification(message, options);
    }
  };
```

from https://github.com/bmcmahen/toasted-notes/blob/master/src/Alert/Toast.tsx#L36

What is happening here? Is it setting it up so that when notify is called on this class, it will call the notify function of 'ToastManager'? Is this common practice? if so what is it called? is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It looks like this is allowing the parent component to call the imperative method, notify(), on the child, so that the API can expose a notify() function to show a toast alert.